# Returning message or notification after completing multi threading task in spring boot rest API

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency, spring-rest

Well i want to perform certain long task concurrently by using java multi threading in spring boot and send some notification after completion of that task.

I have wrote a task that perform batch save to the database inside runnable and i am able to insert data to the database but I want to return some message or notification after completing that task. This is the first time i have tried multi threading in spring boot application.

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class UserService{

private static final int THREAD_NUMBER = 4;
private final ExecutorService executerService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_NUMBER);

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepo;

public void saveMultipleUser(List<User> users) throws Exception{
Runnable runnable = () =>{
userRepo.save(users);

//after completeing above task i want to send notification or message to the 
//user. Is there is any system or anything to do this?

}
executerService.execute(runnable);
}
}
```

Comment: You can use a messaging system like Kafka or Rabbitmq, or if you're on AWS, use something like Amazon SNS.

Comment: What is stopping you from sending the message/notification from the runnable itself (after the save() call)?